# Return a set of contacts from a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am struggling to get a query to work. The tables involved are **`acp_tasks`** and **`acp_contacts`**

the only thing the same in both are the ID **`acp_contacts.id = acp_tasks.entity_id`**.

What I am trying to do is **return all the tasks that have been created by different types of Contact**. In this example I am trying to recreate the tasks of the Creditor and additional creditor contacts.
The different types of contact are in the **`acp_contact`**`(creditor_contact, additional_creditor_contact, debtor_contact, additional_debtor_contact)` table

The query below is selecting each task 5 times. Which I am really confused about. could anyone possibly help?

I really appreciate it.

```
SELECT t.id 
     , t.document_id 
     , t.name 
     , t.customer_notes 
     , t.expect_response 
     , t.response_from 
     , t.task_type 
     , t.date_entered 
     , t.date_complete 
     , t.status 
     , t.direction 
     , t.read 
     , t.debt_id 
     , t.entity_id
     , c.link_type
  FROM acp_tasks t
  JOIN acp_contacts c
    ON c.id = t.entity_id
   AND t.status = 'complete'
   AND t.public = 'y'
   AND t.debt_id = 'qcArxlvANQSEAg4f6c66211cf88'
   AND c.link_type IN('creditor_contact','additional_creditor_contact')
 ORDER 
    BY date_complete DESC
```

Comment: Or use `distinct` to fetch distinct record list from/in the output.

Comment: make sure date_complete is not in both of the tables.if so add the table name with it.Other ,make sure any condition is not failing.To check this just try left join to test

Comment: Use DISTINCT, not GROUP BY. Under certain circumstances, the GROUP BY result will be erroneous. Plus, if you use GROUP BY it looks like you don't know what you're doing. Also, note that `read` is a reserved word. I know that you encapsulated everything in backticks, but still, it's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks you everybody, especially, pratik garg and Strawberry for telling me to use DISTINCT. This worked a treat. Been racking my brains this one!!

Cant thank you enough